# Can't Deserialize HashMap using jackson

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson

im writing a client/server application . im serializing my Objest on the server using jackson and send it to my client , and there when im trying to Deserialize it back to the HashMap it will throw this error :

```
Can not instantiate value of type [map type; class java.util.HashMap, [simple type, class java.lang.String] -> [simple type, class java.lang.String]] from JSON String; no single-String constructor/factory method
```

think that im having HashMap:

here is how im serializing it on the server :

```
 @JsonUnwrapped
    public static String convertObjectToJson(Object object) throws IOException {
        ObjectWriter objectWriter = new ObjectMapper().writer().withDefaultPrettyPrinter();
        String json = objectWriter.writeValueAsString(object);
        return json;
    }
```

here is how im deserialize it on the client side :

```
@JsonCreator
    public static <T, E> HashMap<T, E> deserializeToHashMap(String json, Class<T> firstType, Class<E> secondType) {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.configure(SerializationConfig.Feature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS, false);
        try {
            TypeFactory typeFactory = mapper.getTypeFactory();
            MapType mapType = typeFactory.constructMapType(HashMap.class, firstType, secondType);
            HashMap<T, E> map = mapper.readValue(json, mapType); //here is where i get the error
            return map;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            return null;
        }
    }
```

here is a simple json string i receive on the client side (it only contains one value and key ):

```
"{\r\n  \"test\" : \"mohammad\"\r\n}"
```

what im doing wrong ?

Comment: That is a JSON String. Its corresponding Java type is a `String`, not a `HashMap`. If you then want to parse that `String` as a `HashMap`, you can do so.

Comment: Id apreciate it if you tell me what should i do

Answer (score 0):

what are the types you use as first and second? which version of Jackson are you using? I tried the exact code with `Map<String, String>` and it is working fine. I am running Java 8 and Jackson 2.6.0

```
    String json = "{\r\n  \"test\" : \"mohammad\"\r\n}";
    try {
        HashMap<String, String> map = deserializeToHashMap(json, String.class, String.class); 
        System.out.println(map);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

public static <T, E> HashMap<T, E> deserializeToHashMap(String json, Class<T> firstType, Class<E> secondType) {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    // mapper.configure(SerializationConfig.Feature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS, false); <- does not compile for me
    try {
        TypeFactory typeFactory = mapper.getTypeFactory();
        JavaType mapType = typeFactory.constructMapType(HashMap.class, firstType, secondType);
        HashMap<T, E> map = mapper.readValue(json, mapType); // here is where i get the error
        return map;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        return null;
    }
}
```

getting output

```
{test=mohammad}
```

Comment: still not working for me . im using jackson 1.9.9 along with java 8 and the first and second are String.class and String.class

Comment: can you upgrade jackson to newer version?

Comment: i did but still not working . i also tried using Gson but no hope !